# Hide past date posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Advanced custom fields plugin and created datepicker field and assigned to posts. Total 8 posts created. 3 posts with past date and 5 posts with future dates.

Now, have to compare those post dates with current date.

And, hide posts if post date lessthan current date.

Display posts if post date greaterthan current date.

This is datepicker custom field. `the_sub_field('event_end_date')`

I have tried with the following code

```
// current date
$current_date = date("d/m/Y");
// start date (Custom field date picker in posts)
$value = get_sub_field( "event_end_date" );
if ($current_date < $value) {
echo 'greater than';
}else{
echo 'Less than';
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, I have tried with that code in my question

Comment: how your code is related to post query ?

Comment: read about https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts this will guide you.

Comment: issue is in date condition.?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `date_query` to hide past posts. Please see below code.

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// current date
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
// start date (Custom field date picker)
$value = get_sub_field( "event_end_date" );
$value_temp = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($value));

if (strtotime($current_date) < strtotime($value_temp)) {
  echo 'greater than';
}else{
  echo 'Less than';
}
```